# "I want to just say..." vs "I just want to say..."

Tags: word-order, colloquial-language

What's the difference? Are they really different, with a nuance, or is it just a matter of preference? Does one point to your level of fluency more than the other?

Made up examples.

1. "I **just want to say** that for all the experience she claims she's had, she is not all that competent."
2. "I **want to just say** that for all..."

Would the position of *just* set the tone for what the speaker is about to say? In "I just want to say..." the speaker might be about to make a comment directed at another comment made earlier or someone and perhaps oppose it or critique it . In "I want to just say..." on the other hand, the speaker may be wanting to add a piece of information, which would keep the tone more neutral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, there wouldn't be any perceived difference between the two sentences.

However, there is a subtle difference in interpretation that *could* be made:

> 1. I just want to say X . . .

This means that the only thing you want to ***do*** is say X. You don't want to run, jump, watch TV, or have dinner. All you want to *do* is say X.

> 2. I want to just say X . . .

This means that the only thing you want to ***say*** is X. You don't want to say anything else. (However, you might *also* want to run, jump, watch TV, or have dinner.)

---

Such a distinction would generally not be made. However, since a difference was asked for, that would be the only subtle one I could think of.

Generally speaking, both *I just want to say* and *I want to just say* are the equivalent of *let me say* or *I want to say*. They are just general introductions to you making a statement about something. The word *just*, barring the really subtle distinction I made, could be dropped altogether.

Comment: You are sooo hilarious!! Such a lighthearted way of making it plain!! Thank you!

Comment: Jason Bassford, do you agree with my later addition to the question? I don't know how to make your name highlighted so that you are alerted to my message.

Comment: @Bahram Yes, the location of a word in a sentence can have a subtle impact, as in the analysis I performed. (The poster of a question or answer will always be notified of any comments. Once somebody *makes* a comment, you can then direct a comment to them specifically. Now that I've made this comment, the system should automatically suggest my name if you start another comment with `@j`.)